# jVectorMap not able to retrieve map object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I have a jQuery vector map defined as follows:

```
<div id="worldMap" style="width:800px;height:550px"></div>
```

In the JS `onReady` function:

```
$('#worldMap').vectorMap({
  map: 'world_en',
  backgroundColor: '#a5bfdd',
  color: '#f4f3f0',
  hoverColor: '#0000ff',
  hoverOpacity: null,
  selectedColor: '#666666',                
  attribute: 'fill',
  enableZoom: true,
  showTooltip: true, 
  values: sample_data,                 
  scaleColors: ['#ffffff', '#a00000'],
  normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',             
  onRegionClick: function(element,code,region) {
    displayInfo(code,region);    
  }
});
```

I set a timer to kick every five minutes to update the map data. The function it calls is:

```
function updateMap() {         
  $.getJSON('docs/testdata.json',function(data) {
    var map=$("#worldMap").vectorMap('get','mapObject');
    map.series.region[0].setValues(data);
  });
}
```

The map displays correctly in the browser with all data points. The problem arises when `updateMap()` is called. It cannot get the `mapObject` (it is always `undefined`). Thinking it was some kind of timing issue, I moved the `var map=$(...` line to immediately after the definition in the `onready` initialization of the map and MAP is still `undefined`.

Comment: Upgraded to newest 2.0.1 version and issue went away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem

I solve it with that :

> ```
> map = new jvm.Map({
>     container: jQuery('#world-map'),
>     map: "map",
>     regionsSelectable: true,
>     regionsSelectableOne: true,
>     backgroundColor: 'transparent',
>     zoomMax: 1,
>     zoomMin: 1,
>     zoomOnScroll: false
> });
> ```

```
map.clearSelectedRegions();
```

Answer (score 4):

Also, try:

```
var obj = $('#world-map .jvectormap-container').data('mapObject');
```

Then:

```
obj.series.region[0].setValues(data);
```